# Check content css in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I check if the content in css is equal to mobile or desktop?

```
var push = document.querySelector('.push-button');
var result = getComputedStyle(push).content;
if ($('.push-button').css('content') == "mobile") {
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.main').css("color", "black");

});
} else if (result ===  "desktop") {
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".push-button").click(function () {
        $('.desktop-menu').slideToggle(1000);
        $('.desktop-menu').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Please explain yourself and provide HTML & CSS codes as well

Comment: there's a problem with your code? You didn't mention exactly what. You state a goal, then give an unexplained code dump. It's hard to work out what to tell you. Also, it would help to show the HTML and CSS you're trying to work with.

Comment: content is in a before?

Comment: I don't think content can be used on an element unless it's in a pseudo-element and you cannot access those using jquery.  You would need to show us what changes that content and the css for that

Comment: Here is the css: @media only screen and (min-width: 730px) { #push-menu { display: none !important; } .push-button { content: "desktop"; } } .push-button { display: -webkit-flex !important; display: -ms-flexbox !important; display: flex !important; content: "mobile"; }

Comment: please edit your question to include extra code and information. Code in comments is particularly hard to read, and may not be seen by everyone reading the question. Thankyou. Also, the HTML is relevant too, as mentioned previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do this

`if ($('.push-button').css('content') == "\"mobile\"") {`

Answer (score 0):

> Information is not sufficient but Check if this can help you

```js
var push = document.getElementByClass(".content");
if (matchMedia) {
  const mq = push.matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)");
  mq.addListener(WidthChange);
  WidthChange(mq);
}
function WidthChange(mq) {
  if (mq.matches) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".push-button").click(function() {
        $('.desktop-menu').slideToggle(1000);
        $('.desktop-menu').css('display', 'block');
      });
    });
  } else {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".push-button").click(function() {
            $('.desktop-menu').slideToggle(1000);
            $('.desktop-menu').css('display', 'block');
          );
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Here is the css: @media only screen and (min-width: 730px) {
    #push-menu {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .push-button {
        content: "desktop";
    }
}                                                                                                                            .push-button {
        display: -webkit-flex !important;
        display: -ms-flexbox !important;
        display: flex !important;
        content: "mobile";
    }